# Override next and previous button paging toolbar sencha extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs, overriding, paging

I have a problem with the paging toolbar in my app. My store is populated by a PHP script that converts a MySQL database table to JSON data.

In my window I have a panel with a form that I use to filter a grid. All the "filters" are passed in a `store.load()` call as parameters and the PHP script complete the query and return data.

My problem is that when I have some filters and I click on next button of paging toolbar my filter disappear and store is loaded without extra params. How can I send extra params in nextPage()/prevPage() call?

EDIT:
I resolved using `store.on('beforeload')`, here's my solution:

```
store.on('beforeload', function(store, operation, opts){
   operation.params={
       // yuor params here
       param1: param1Value,
       param2: param2Value
   };
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override moveNext and movePrevious methods of Paging toolbar, in those methods you can pass an object which contains all the custom params that you need to pass to PHP

```
/**
 * Move to the next page, has the same effect as clicking the 'next' button.
 */
moveNext : function(){
    var me = this,
        total = me.getPageData().pageCount,
        next = me.store.currentPage + 1;

    if (next <= total) {
        if (me.fireEvent('beforechange', me, next) !== false) {
            me.store.nextPage({
                // all the custom params should go here
                param1 : 'value1'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This will easily fix your current problem, but if you want a generic fix where store will provide these custom params everytime when previous/next page is fetched from store then you can override the loadPage method and add custom params there

```
loadPage: function(page, options) {
    var me = this;

    me.currentPage = page;

    // add your custom params
    options = Ext.apply({
        param1 : 'value1'
    }, options);

    // Copy options into a new object so as not to mutate passed in objects
    options = Ext.apply({
        page: page,
        start: (page - 1) * me.pageSize,
        limit: me.pageSize,
        addRecords: !me.clearOnPageLoad
    }, options);

    if (me.buffered) {
        return me.loadToPrefetch(options);
    }
    me.read(options);
}
```

Reference:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Paging.html#Ext-toolbar-Paging

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-nextPage

Comment: Doesn't work, I used a parameter to try this solution and when I click Next the store is reloaded without parameters. I posted my code in the question above

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you found your answer but I had the same problem and here is what I found.

Hope it helps.

When you make a call with parameters, it is only for one time. In previous versions Sencha tells to use baseParams but I wasnt able to find it in newer ones. So I used extraParams of Proxy this way:

This is the form button i use to filter my data

```
text: 'Filter',
handler: function() {
        /*
        get the form
        get a record object and set its data
        */
        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
        var record = form.getRecord();
        form.updateRecord(record);

        for(name in record.data){
            if (record.data.hasOwnProperty(name))
                envelopeStore.setExtraParam(name, record.data[name]);
        }
        /*
        envelopeStore.getProxy().extraParams = record.data;
        *I have some constant params so I needed to add them in a loop as above
        *you can simply use this
        */

        envelopeGrid.child('pagingtoolbar').moveFirst(); 
        /*
        do not load store data. It does not change paging. go to first page instead
        */
    }
```